# Map in Angular 10 array of list objects

Tags: angular

This is **WORKING** service class for which return  single  transaction

```
getEditTransactionById(id: number): Observable<ITransaction> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Result<ITransaction>>(baseUrl'/Transaction/GetEditTransactionById'+ `/${id}`)       
    .pipe(
        map((res)=>{
            res.data.valueDate = new Date(res.data.valueDate);       
            return res.data;
        })
    )
}
```

Actually how I need to change the date format of fields valuedate in  array coming from API

Could you please help?

This is my service class which returns array ..**.Need to change the date format**

```
getTransactions(): Observable<ITransactionResponse[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Result<ITransactionResponse[]>>(baseUrl + '/Transaction/GetTransactions')
    .pipe(map( res => res.data));
}
```

This is my Model:

```
export class ITransactionResponse {
    id: number;
    transactionNo?:string;
    valueDate?:Date;
    amount?: number;
}
```

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: i need to change the date format of  valueDate?:Date; of array from json

Comment: i already done in using pipe with map  for sinlge object

Comment: you did already, what else do you want map?

Comment: @naren in the question i have mention getEditTransactionById.. i need same for getTransactions

Comment: You already map `res` to `res.data`, so why don't you also map every entry of `res.data` the way you do it in your other service? If you don't know how to iterate over a list maybe start with the basics first.

Comment: sory ..am  .net developer and  leaning angular and  map...syntax is my issue

Comment: TypeScript totally supports `for` loops

Comment: @Smutje  so why don't you also map every entry of res.data the way you do it in your other service   ..am getting error  screen shot attached..

Comment: `res.data` is of type `ITransactionResponse[]>` so you might need a loop over all entries probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this

```
getTransactions(): Observable<ITransactionResponse[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Result<ITransactionResponse[]>>(baseUrl + '/Transaction/GetTransactions')
    .pipe(map( res => {
           res.data.map(item => {
             item = new Date(item.valueDate)
           })
           return res.data;
     }));
}
```

To

```
getTransactions(): Observable<ITransactionResponse[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Result<ITransactionResponse[]>>(baseUrl + '/Transaction/GetTransactions')
    .pipe(map( (res : any) => res.data));
}
```

This is happening because you didn't specify the type of your incoming `res` and you are trying to access `res.data.valueDate` so compiler doesn't know the nested fields of res because default type of `res` is not an `object`

Comment: Thanks ...But i have to change the format of field valueDate  in array

Comment: did you try what i mentioned in my answer?

Comment: i tried but actally date is showing 2020-11-26T00:00:00 like that..  i need to format dd-mm-yyyy...so i need to convert all dates in array..( i can change to date to string in the model) is there any solution..

Comment: your array is coming in which key? in `res` or in `res.data` ?

Comment: Thnks a lot ...its working ..small changes ..i used moment t convert date to string ...I have replaced date with string..is it possible with date field with format change( i need DD-MM-YYYY)

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can checkout `moment` documentation for `format` options

Answer (score 0):

After mapping the result to get list of ITransactionResponse, you can map the list of ITransactionResponse, like `res.map(x => x.valueDate = new Date(x.valueDate))`

Comment: i tried  nut no luck ..could u please append in my method